# Pinescript, Plot Title Displaying realtime float numbers?

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to have a float value and display it in the title= section on a plot line

Example Code:

```
var float adjustedStoploss = 3000.00

{ some code }

*// This following code doesn't work - is it possible to convert that float to something that can be displayed
// in the title= section of a plot... thanks in advance!!*

plot( adjustedStoploss , **title="Stop Loss Value: "+adjustedStoploss** , linewidth=3, style=plot.style_line, color=#28B463  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. But you can see a plot's value at a specific time with your mouse.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
plot(close)
```

[image]